# VBA macros not executing a bat file

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, macros

I have bat file that starts and executes a testing tool silently. Double click manually the bat file does what it needs to do.
Now i write a VBA macro that needs to execute the bat file, But the macro just opens and immediately closes it.
find below the macro code.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim WshShell As Object
Set WshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = Trim(CStr(Excel.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)))
Output = WshShell.Run("Command.bat", 1, True)
End Sub
```

cell(1,1) in sheet one has the directory where command.bat file is present.
What wrong am i doing?

Comment: Have you tried to execute it like Output = WshShell.Run("C:\Mypath\Command.bat", 1, True) just to test *.bat file?

Comment: Yes i did, and that gives me an error 'Method run of the shell object failed'

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions to run a batch file in the target directory?

Comment: When i manual double click on the bat file i am able to execute so i am assuming that i have the permission. Can you elaborate if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: My path is C:\WorkspaceRFT\RMS\command.bat doesn't contain any spaces

Comment: What about `Output = WshShell.Run("cmd.exe /C Command.bat", 1, True)`? also with full paths to `cmd.exe` and/or the batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying it this way? I have tested this on a local bat file and it executes fine for me.

```
Dim Foldername As String
Foldername = "C:\WorkspaceRFT\RMS\command.bat"
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. As others have mentioned building the path to the variable is a bit finicky, especially when your file path has a space. Using `Chr(34)` to represent a `"` works well here.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim WshShell As Object: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim MyPath as String: MyPath = Trim(CStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)))
    Output = WshShell.Run(Chr(34) & myPath & "\Command.bat" & Chr(34), 1, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, This is not helping either, same problem with this code as well.

Comment: What was the value of `output`? Did you receive an error? Does `Debug.Print Chr(34) & myPath & "\Command.bat" & Chr(34)` match the path to the .Bat file?

Comment: Hi Ryan, there is no error as such coming. It opens the cmd and closes it immediately. Cant really see if the commands written in .bat file was loaded either. And yes the path mentioned in code is correct. When the bat file executed it should open the RFT testing tool load a test script and execute it (This happens when i manually double click execute the bat file)